# Is there a address book app compatible with django 1.5 ('verify_exists')

Tags: django, compatibility, addressbook, django-1.5

As in title- I'm too lazy to code such a basic functionality found django-addressbook but it's incompatible with 1.5 because of verify_exist depreciation.
My first thought was to fall back to django 1.4 but I need to keep focus on security with this system and something tells me that old django would't do good in terms of security.
Does any one know about such an app - preferable in active development.

Comment: Why don't you fork the code and change the two `verify_exists` lines in `models.py`? it's literally just a case of removing them.

Comment: after reading the docs I admit there in no obvious security risk in deleting this validator. is it? if anybody think there is...

Comment: It was removed in the first place, precisely because of security issues: http://git.io/28h_ZA

Comment: I'm hmmm... how to say that and don't lie... I'm forcing django address-book to work with 1.5 will post on bitbucket when I'm done (but I don't promise all strings will be still in english - fell tha pain of translation you English speaking ...) ;P

Comment: I have pull requests on Github for this project, to make it work in Django 1.5: https://github.com/iiilx/django-addressbook/pulls